# Prove that $ V (\cap_{j \neq i} I_j) \cap V(I_i) = \emptyset $.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am stuck in seemingly simple problem.

> Consider in the ring $ k[X_1,\dots,X_n] $ an ideal $ I $ s.t. $ V(I) = \{P_1,\dots, P_N\} $. Let $ I_i = I(\{P_i\}) $ denote the distinct maximal ideals which contain $ P_i $. Prove that $ V (\cap_{j \neq i} I_j) \cap V(I_i) = \emptyset $.

We can easily prove that $ V (\cap_{j \neq i} I_j) \neq \emptyset $ and that $ V(I_i) = \{P_i\}$.
(a) Can we say anything explicit about $ V (\cap_{j \neq i} I_j) $ ? (for e.g. that it contains all $ P $'s except $ P_i $)?
(b) I am not able to prove (think of the argument) that $ P_i \notin V (\cap_{j \neq i} I_j) $ (assuming it's true, which must be the case).

Comment: Hint: Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: @KReiser Sorry, but this doesn't ring any bell to me. Could you please give some more hint?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Generalization_to_arbitrary_rings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following property of algebraic sets to solve this problem:

$$
V(I \cap J) = V(I) \cup V(J).
$$

So, $V (\cap_{j \neq i} I_j) = \{P_1,\dots,P_N \} - \{P_i \}$.